# File I/O on a mounted USB storage device in USB Host mode

Tags: java, android, file-io, usb

I'm making an Android app where I need to browse the contents of an attached external device, download files from the device to the phone/tablet and copy some files back to the attached usb storage device. I'm so far able to detect or enumerate devices attached. However I can't see documentation regarding how to list the files on the device, browse directories, copy/movie files to and from the external device, etc.

The only thing I found was this stackoverflow question:
[File I/O on a mounted USB storage device in USB Host mode (Android 3.1 and up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371715/file-i-o-on-a-mounted-usb-storage-device-in-usb-host-mode-android-3-1-and-up)

Is there a high level api for this or one has to deal with low level stuff and protocols? Is there, maybe, some library ready to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26285154/115145 would seem to be the relevant answer from the question that you linked to.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but thought that maybe there was something else, or some ready-to-use library out there?

Comment: problem is that : *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: Ok, maybe someone can provide the source code for copying files from/to storage devices.

Comment: That would still be a code search.  Additionally, the task is many times more complicated than could be posted in an SO answer - you need a full implementation of the filesystem utilized.